# What do you think is the best way to promote a Twitter account in an app?

Tags: mobile-application, labels, username, twitter

I have an app and on the "About" page, there is a label which says `Handmade coded by`, then a button which makes the user follow me (the developer) on Twitter.

The question is, what do you think it should the button say? "Follow @myName" or just "@myName" (to be coherent with the label which is over the button).

It should be noted that when the user presses the button, it follows me on Twitter and then the app shows my profile page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app makes your user follow you, then you better say so explicitly.

I'm not sure what the nature of your app is, and if all users necessarily will have a Twitter account or not, but I would suggest only having your button link to your account page, and allow users once there to decide whether to follow you or not.

Test this out and get some feedback from real users before implementing. Myself personally, I'm selective in who I follow and so I would probably not click the button. However if I could see what you tweet out I could decide and give you a chance or not.

Comment: That's a very good advice. I will try it, thanks! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Does the use of Twitter add something useful to most of your users, or is it just something that you think would be nice?  If it doesn't add anything useful for most users, then I wouldn't make it prominent.  Putting it somewhere like the "About" page, is a good choice here.  As it's findable by someone that is looking for it, but not in the way for every other user.

If somehow it's a useful thing to most of your users, then I would include it as a link in the *action overflow* (or equivalent) button.  However think about this carefully, as the majority of the time, Twitter is more about the ego of the developer than about adding something useful to your users.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to "promote" anything to your users is to **demonstrate its value** to them.

Perhaps the best way to demonstrate your Twitter account's value is to give your users a *sample feed* from it, and to display your twitter account and information (as you've already done).  If your users are convinced that your feed is of value to them, they are much more likely to click on the button in your application to follow the account.